# Regex to match all the words looking for

Tags: regex

Match all the number or word in the same tag using RegEx.

I am trying to match all the number or word in the sentence below.

Sentence: `<tag>123<tag>abc<tag>efg<tag>456<tag>`

I am using below RegEx expression

RegEx: `<tag>(.*?)<tag>`

But it can only capture '123' and 'efg'.

May I know how can I capture all the contents (123,abc,efg,456) in the tag?

Comment: Hint: look arounds or split

Comment: If overlapping for matching contiguous use e.g. a lookahead [`<tag>([^<]*)(?=<tag>)`](https://regex101.com/r/jQncki/1) like @anubhava already hinted.